# IAM Policy to deny upgrading existing instances to certain ec2 instance types

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I've been trying to create an IAM policy that denies users from modifying an instance type beyond a certain size. For example, if a user wants to modify an ec2 instance of t3a.micro to t3a.small, they should be allowed. But for cost saving reasons, they should be denied modifying increasing an instance to lets say *.large instance types.

Is this possible?

I've been trying to come up with a condition for ec2:ModifyInstanceAttribute but can't seem to get it down.

Here is my policy as it stands, but it only disallows changing the instance based on the current type, not the target type.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "LimitEC2policy",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RunInstances",
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:ModifyInstanceAttribute"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringNotLike": {
                    "ec2:InstanceType": [
                        "*.nano",
                        "*.small",
                        "*.micro",
                        "*.medium"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from AWS Support is that this is not possible, as ec2:InstanceType filters by the type of instance that is currently running. So it's not possible to filter by the target type.